# how can I pass parameters in a lambda expression? Tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, lambda

I have a key pad in tkinter made of buttons, when clicked they add their number to a string "Amount Entered" which will be converted to a float at the end.

```py
AmountEntered = ""

Number = tk.Button(self, text = "7", command = lambda AmountEntered: AmountEntered + "7")
Number.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky='nsew')
```

however when clicked, I get the error 
**TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'AmountEntered'**

I thought that the first AmountEntered would be the parameter, what does this refer to?

Comment: Your question is ***"pass parameters ..."***: Where is your function, you want to **pass** the parameter? [Edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with the lambda expression; the problem in the assumption that the callback function will be called with an argument. It won't be. `AmountEntered` really is a global variable, so all you need is

```
Number = tk.Button(self, text="7", command=lambda: AmountEntered + "7")
```